# Hashing by Persistent's Entity key?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to build a `Data.HashMap` structure by grouping multiple Persistent entities by their foreign key field. E.g. say I have these two entities ([straight out of the Yesod book](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent#persistent_code_generation))

```
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show
BlogPost
    title String
    authorId PersonId
    deriving Show
```

and I want a:

```
HashMap PersonId [BlogPost]
```

The challenge here is that PersonId does not directly implement `Hashable` (from Data.Hashable) and additionally it's abstracted depending on which DB you're using (Postgres in my case).

I suppose (just a wild beginner guess) I could implement Hashable for PersonId myself by doing `fromPersistValue` and a `read` into an Int64, for which there's a Hashable implementation already, but I imagine there might be a less convoluted way of achieving that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it have to be a `HashMap`? `Data.Map` only needs `Ord`. The `Hashable` class is a bit dodgy and could use a fix-up anyway.

Unless you know what you're doing and understand the flaws in the hashing behavior of `Hashable` you should never use `HashMap` where a `Data.Map` would do.

This has the side effect of avoiding unnecessary orphan instances. (More things are Ord than Hashable)

Answer (score 6):

You can do this for the price of a few orphan instances. You can find the complete code below.

`PersonId` is just an alias for `KeyBackend SqlBackend Person`, so the `instance Hashable (KeyBackend b e)` is what you need. The rest of the declarations derive `Hashable` for other types that may end up being parts of `PersonId`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module HashableInstances where

import Database.Persist
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Hashable
import Data.Time
import Data.Fixed

instance HasResolution e => Hashable (Fixed e) where
  hashWithSalt s = (hashWithSalt s :: Double -> Int) . realToFrac
deriving instance Generic Day
instance Hashable Day
deriving instance Generic LocalTime
instance Hashable LocalTime
deriving instance Generic TimeOfDay
instance Hashable TimeOfDay
deriving instance Generic TimeZone
instance Hashable TimeZone
instance Hashable DiffTime where
  hashWithSalt s = (hashWithSalt s :: Double -> Int) . realToFrac
deriving instance Generic UTCTime
instance Hashable UTCTime
deriving instance Generic ZonedTime
instance Hashable ZonedTime
deriving instance Generic ZT
instance Hashable ZT
deriving instance Generic PersistValue
instance Hashable PersistValue
deriving instance Generic (KeyBackend b e)
instance Hashable (KeyBackend b e)
```

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer, this is a great point of reference if I have to implement Hashable for those types down the line. Blog-post worthy.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Roman's answer for recent (2.x) versions of Persistent:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

module HashableInstances where

import Database.Persist
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Hashable
import Data.Time

deriving instance Generic Day
instance Hashable Day
deriving instance Generic LocalTime
instance Hashable LocalTime
deriving instance Generic TimeOfDay
instance Hashable TimeOfDay
deriving instance Generic TimeZone
instance Hashable TimeZone
instance Hashable DiffTime where
  hashWithSalt s = (hashWithSalt s :: Double -> Int) . realToFrac
deriving instance Generic UTCTime
instance Hashable UTCTime
deriving instance Generic ZonedTime
instance Hashable ZonedTime
deriving instance Generic PersistValue
instance Hashable PersistValue

instance (PersistEntity a) => Hashable (Key a) where
  hashWithSalt s k = hashWithSalt s $ keyToValues k
```